# Django how to test if message is sent

Tags: django, testing

I want to test if message is sent to user after submit. I'm using [django.contrib.messages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/). Everything seems to be working during manual testing (runserver), but in unit test I don't get messages.

Code that stores message:

```
messages.success(request, _('Internationalized evil message.'))
```

Code that should test message:

```
from django.contrib.messages.api import get_messages

...

def test_message_should_sent_to_user(self):
    """After successful phone number submit, message should be displayed."""
    response = self.client.post(
        reverse('evil.views.evil_data_submit'), self.valid_data)
    messages = get_messages(response.request)
    self.assertNotEqual(len(messages), 0)
```

It looks like that no middleware is called during test client post method call.

---

**Update after @Tisho [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11455756/django-how-to-test-if-message-is-sent/11457068#11457068)**

Messages should be found in `response.context`, even my guts say that it should work, but it doesn't. I've placed `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` in django/contrib/messages/context_processors.py to see if its called during test `client.post`, its not.

I've double checked `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`, `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` and `INSTALLED_APPS` - probably tomorrow I'll discover that I missed something.

---

**Important detail**

Forgot to mention that in case of successful submit view returns **HttpResponseRedirect** therefore `response.context` is empty.

---

**Solution**

View returns redirect (which has no context data), to solve that we can pass `follow=True` to client.post method (method suggested by @Tisho).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

During unit tests, the message could be found in

```
response = self.client.post(
    reverse('evil.views.evil_data_submit'), self.valid_data)
messages = response.context['messages']
```

If your view returns a redirect, `response.context` will be empty unless you pass `follow=True`, like so:

```
response = self.client.post(
    reverse('evil.views.evil_data_submit'),
    self.valid_data,
    follow=True)
```

Comment: I thought it should be there, but it isn't :/.

Comment: Do you have different settings file for unit tests? Seems like a wrong settings for me.

Comment: No, the same one. I even did `pdb.trace()` at my test after `cliet.post()` to check whats in configs, everything as I expect. Probaly I missed something.

Comment: What `MESSAGE_STORAGE` do you use ?

Comment: django.contrib.messages.storage.session.SessionStorage

Comment: Try with CookieStorage for tests.

Comment: Hmm, you say there is a redirect and an empty context. Did you try `self.client.post(reverse('evil.views.evil_data_submit'), self.valid_data, follow=True)` ?

Comment: it doesn't work if  response.status=302. In this case response.context=None . Im working on solving this problem too.

Comment: @Oduvan, in case of 302/redirect add follow=True as last param, and it will work. It is explained in the last part of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The best way I found is by using mock

http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#patch-methods-start-and-stop

```
class SimpleCommentTestDirect(TestCase):

def setUp(self):
    self._patcher1 = patch('django.contrib.messages.error')
    self.mock_error = self._patcher1.start()

def tearDown(self):
    self._patcher1.stop()

def test_error_message(self):
    self.client.get('/vote/direct/unknownapp/comment/1/up/')
    self.assertEqual(self.mock_error.call_args[0][1], 'Wrong request. Model.')
```

BTW: There are also should be a way to get request by using mock. And by using request object get message from django.contrib.messages.get_messages